# MySQL count the number of count of email occurrences separated by countries

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

I need to compose a MySQL query, which will count the number of email occurrences per each country

I have following mysql table (shop_orders)

| order_id | email | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test@gmail.com | _it |
| 2 | test-2@gmail.com | _hu |
| 3 | test-3@gmail.com | _de |
| 4 | test@gmail.com | _pl |
| 5 | test@gmail.com | _it |

Desired output

| count | _it | _hu | _de | _pl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

So far I have managed to do is fetch the count, how many time email appears.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count, email
FROM
    pinkpanda.shop_orders
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

But now I need to count off all the counts of emails and separate the data for each country

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide.

Comment: Which mysql version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to group data by the number of emails per country:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count_, email, country
  FROM
    shop_orders
  GROUP BY email, country
  ORDER BY count_ DESC
)
select count_, 
       sum(case when country = '_it' then 1 else 0 end) as _it,
       sum(case when country = '_hu' then 1 else 0 end) as _hu,
       sum(case when country = '_de' then 1 else 0 end) as _de,
       sum(case when country = '_pl' then 1 else 0 end) as _pl
from cte
group by count_
```

This is a valid solution for old mysql :

```
select count_, 
       sum(case when country = '_it' then 1 else 0 end) as _it,
       sum(case when country = '_hu' then 1 else 0 end) as _hu,
       sum(case when country = '_de' then 1 else 0 end) as _de,
       sum(case when country = '_pl' then 1 else 0 end) as _pl
from (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count_, email, country
  FROM
    shop_orders
  GROUP BY email, country
  ORDER BY count_ DESC
) cte
group by count_
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/A4aAvbKg)

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that everything is right for you, and let me know if more adjustment is necessary.

```
SELECT country, email, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM shop_orders
GROUP BY country, email
ORDER BY country, occurrences DESC
```

Output:
[image]